# Pyomo: variables with domain set of multiple individual values

Tags: python, python-3.x, solver, pyomo

I have a very complex problem I have to solve using a solver.

I have a few variables where possible values are stored in an array so for example x1 cant any value between 0 and 1 except the ones specified in possible_values.

The following example is a very small part of my model so using a few loops to find the solution is not an option.

The Problem is that I cant use the possible_values array as a domain in the Var function.

Do you have and ideas how this might work?

```
model = ConcreteModel()

possible_values = [0.1,0.25,0.2,0.05,0.4,0.15,0.75]  # add up to 1

model.x1 = Var(domain=possible_values)
model.x2 = Var(domain=possible_values)
model.x3 = Var(domain=possible_values)
model.x4 = Var(domain=possible_values)
model.x5 = Var(domain=possible_values)
model.x6 = Var(domain=possible_values)

obj_expr = 3*model.x2 + 1*model.x3 + 2*model.x4 + 7*model.x5 + 9*model.x6 + 10*model.x7 

model.minimizer = Objective(expr=obj_expr, sense=maximize)

model.const1 = Constraint(expr=model.x1 + model.x2 <= 0.3)
model.const2 = Constraint(expr=model.x4 + model.x3 >= 0.25)

solver.solve(model);

#values xN should all be different
print(value(model.x1)) #should be one of possible_values
print(value(model.x2)) #should be one of possible_values
print(value(model.x3)) #should be one of possible_values
print(value(model.x4)) #should be one of possible_values
print(value(model.x5)) #should be one of possible_values
print(value(model.x6)) #should be one of possible_values
```

> ```
> > [0.1, 0.25, 0.2, 0.05, 0.4, 0.15, 0.75] is not a valid domain.
> > Variable domains must be an instance of a Pyomo Set.  Examples:
> > NonNegativeReals, Integers, Binary
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to handle the domain piece differently...obviously.  :)

here is an idea that should work.  The example shows an `x` variable that has cardinality of two that can take on one of 3 values.  Also enforced is the concept that all `x_i` must be different.

```
# weird domain

import pyomo.environ as pyo

### DATA

domain = {  0 : 0.3,
            1 : 0.5,
            2 : 0.7}

constants = {   0: 5,
                1: 2}

#### MODEL
model = pyo.ConcreteModel('oddball domain')

### SETS
model.I = pyo.Set(initialize=range(2))   # x index
model.DI = pyo.Set(initialize=domain.keys())   # domain index

### PARAMETERS
# note:  These aren't totally necessary, you could just work with python dictionaries
#        but it adds clarity to the model
model.vals = pyo.Param(model.DI, initialize=domain)
model.c = pyo.Param(model.I, initialize=constants)

### VARIABLES
model.x = pyo.Var(model.I, model.DI, domain=pyo.Binary)

### OBJ
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(model.x[i,di]*model.vals[di]*model.c[i] 
                            for i in model.I
                            for di in model.DI), sense=pyo.maximize)

### CONSTRAINTS
# Only one.  For each x-index, we need to sum accross the domain and limit 
# the selection to 1 or less
def only_one(m, i):
    return sum(m.x[i,di] for di in m.DI) <= 1
model.C1 = pyo.Constraint(model.I, rule=only_one)

# All different.  Each x_i must be unique
def unique(m, di):
    return sum(m.x[i,di] for i in m.I) <= 1
model.C2 = pyo.Constraint(model.DI, rule=unique)

#model.pprint()


solver = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
results = solver.solve(model)
print(results)

for i in model.I:
    for di in model.DI:
        if model.x[i,di].value:
            print(f'x[{i}] = {model.vals[di]}')
```

#### Yields:

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 4.5
  Upper bound: 4.5
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 6
  Number of variables: 7
  Number of nonzeros: 13
  Sense: maximize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: optimal
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 1
      Number of created subproblems: 1
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.010771036148071289
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

x[0] = 0.7
x[1] = 0.5
```